# Rails share cache between web and worker on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, sidekiq, worker

I have a Rails application which has both web process and background worker (running Sidekiq).

I have one feature which write value to cache from web process, then the worker read this value from cache later.

In web:

```
Rails.cache.write 'key', 'xxx'
```

In worker:

```
Rails.cache.read 'key'
```

This works find on my local environment, but when I deploy this code to Heroku, the worker can NOT read corresponding key from cache, it always returns nil.

I am wondering if there is any special config I ignored for production mode?

Comment: are you using a 3rd party add-on for your redis service? Have you confirmed you're connecting to the same/correct redis instance? Add-ons should provide something like `REDIS_URL` that both your web and worker instances need to be connecting to

Answer (score 4):

The default cache store in Rails is `filestore` which means the cache is stored on disk.

From the [Rails guide on caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-filestore)

> This is the default cache store implementation.

Your worker and web process **do not** share the same filesystem, the dynos are spawned in totally different environments, which do not share resources.

If you want to share the cache, you will need to store it centrally in a place that they can both access.

This means probably means a datastore such as [Memcache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memcachestore) or [Redis](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails).

There are many [Memcache and Redis addons available on Heroku](https://addons.heroku.com/#data-stores).